# [[I cannot be cast to [I Exception

Tags: java, scjp

Can anyone explain this exception and what is actually happening in this code:

```
public class Dims {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1, 2,}, {3, 4}};
        int[] b = (int[]) a[1];
        Object o1 = a;
        int[][] a2 = (int[][]) o1;
        int[] b2 = (int[]) o1; //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to [I
        System.out.println(b[1]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int[]` is incompatible with `int[][]`, so you can't convert one to another, but you're trying to do it. The runtime type of `o1` is `int[][]` and you're trying to cast it to `int[]`.

OK, and why the types are called `[[I` and `[I`?  You may try to run `int[].class.toString()` and `int[][].class.toString` to understand that. The `int[].class` would be represented with the code `[` (which means array of) `I` (which means integer), and `int[][].class` would be represented by `[[`  (which means array of arrays) of `I` (integer).

Comment: What is this line doing `int[] b = (int[]) a[1];`

Comment: That is not relevant. a[1] actually is an array of ints, so you could easily have said: int[] b = a[1]; This is not the case with int[][] and int[] , which are two different types.

Comment: @kittu the line, which you've written is equivalent to `int[] b = a[i]`, because you don't need casting. `int[][]` is an array of arrays of integer and if you're trying to get element by index, you're getting an array of integers (`int[]`) and therefore you don't need any casting, because `b` is `int[]`.

Comment: `int[] b = (int[]) a[1];` Why only `a[1]` here? If I use `int[] b = (int[]) a[2];` it says index out of bound exception

Comment: @kittu of course, you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundException`, because your index is out of bound `[0; 1]`, which are defined for array of size 2.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you are casting 2d array to 1d

`[[I` represent class of 2d array

`[[` represenst 2d array

`[I` represent class of 1d array

`[`  represents 1d array

`I` is the integer

Answer (score 1):

you can not cast 2-D array to 1-D array. here you are getting same `[[I cannot be cast to [I` because `o1 is internally pointing to 2_D integer array and b2 is 1-D array`.

instead of that line you can do as :

```
int[] b2 =  ((int[][])o1)[0];
```

here `[[I` means compiler wraps primitive type to Integer class and created 2-D array object of Integer type. `[I` means 1-D array of Integer Type.